# React.js Route not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router

my `/` route doesn't properly render my main component.

Her is my code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" componenet={Main}>
            <IndexRoute component={Index}></IndexRoute>
            <Route path="portfolio" component={Portfolio}></Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

This is my Main component:

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {     
    render() {
        console.log("asdfasfsaf");
        return(
        <div>
            <h1> This is Main Page </h1>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Once i load the website it doesn't console log anything nor render `<h1>` This is main page header. Also If I delete this `Main` componenet it still goes to my `IndexRoute` without any error which is my index componenet.

Comment: What URL are you serving your site from. Are you serving it from http://localhost/ or something like http://localhost/my-site/public ?

Comment: it's just localhost:8080

Comment: Is there any error in your console?

Comment: no error in console

Comment: So, `/portfolio` loads correctly and `/` does not? What does the `render` method of `Portfolio` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" componenet={Main}>
            <IndexRoute component={Index}></IndexRoute>
            <Route path="portfolio" component={Portfolio}></Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
  ), document.getElementById('app'));
```